# C++ | Dealing with JSON strings with json_spirit

Tags: c++, json

I am obliged to use json_spirit for a certain project, but this is the first time i deal with it.

I have a string like this:

```
QString str = " {\"Name\":\"Jhon\",\"Age\":\"15\"}";
```

Then i do:

```
mValue json;
if(read_string(str.toStdString(), json)) {

    mObject jsonObject = json.get_obj();
    [...]
}
```

Now, how can i get the value of "Name" or "Age"?

Thank you.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I would recommend [rapidjson](https://github.com/miloyip/rapidjson).

Comment: I would suggest boost::property_tree as you seem to already have boost installed.